# three divs side by side which floats to right and responsive

Tags: html, css

Dropdown1 and Dropdown2 must float to right. Paging must be to the right.
Paging content may reduce and dropdown1 and 2 must adjust accordingly. I tried different ways but unable to get the solution. In mobile device all the three divs must be centered.

[image]

We are using bootstrap. Divs are as follows

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 alpha omega">



                  <!-- Title -->

        </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 alpha omega">

            <div style="float:right">

                <ul class="nav">

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" id="sortby">Drop Down 2<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu " style="text-transform:uppercase;">
                            <li data-filterkind="$p" data-filtervalue="DESC">
                                <a href="./" >1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li data-filterkind="$p" data-filtervalue="ASC">
                                <a href="./" >2</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
               <!-- Drop down 2 -->
            </div>
        </div>


            </div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 alpha omega">

            <div style="float:right" >

                  <!-- Pagination -->
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Please suggest

Comment: The navigation bar is not on the top, in between the page.

Comment: How about including your CSS as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So like this?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-center heading1">
            <p> Heading </p><!-- Heading -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="float text-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <p> DD1</P><!-- Drop down 1 -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">  
                        <p> DD2</P><!-- Drop down 2 -->     
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">  
                        <p> PAGINATION</P><!-- pagination -->       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then add the following additional stuff to your custom CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) 
{
    .float
        {
            float: right;
        }
    .heading1
        {
            text-align: left;
        }
}
```

FYI - The above is bootstrap, but the additional classes are needed to get the custom result you want.

Comment: we are using bootstrap. I am trying to display Heading, two dropdownlist and pagination above list of items. Heading on the left and rest of three items must float to the right.

Comment: Also in mobile they must be centered.

Comment: Yes the navigation bar is in between page. Its as per requirement. I tried using floats and all but tjhey are not aligned properly. One more requirement is paging content will be changing, so the three items must adjust accordingly. Same as bar in https://www.modaoperandi.com/shop website

Comment: Okay. So do mean this: when mobile view (up to 768px) you want the heading centered on one line, then the three items displaying equally apart on the second line. Then above mobile (from 768px) you want all on one line, but with the group off to the right. IS that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. Above mobile (from 768px) you want all on one line, Heading to left and rest three group off to the right. In mobile view all the four will be stacked. Like heading in one row, DD1 in row2, DD2 in row3, Paging in row4. All content centered.

Comment: with the above layout, note that it is in"container" so there is padding left and right. You can use "container-fluid" which will remove padding, but you may need to then apply padding to the right side as float right will probably push the last element off screen.